# jQuery Error (skadate)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using SkaDate and it's returning the error as below:

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: input[@type='checkbox'][@name ='match_religion[]']
```

so, site stoped working , any help? I am using jQuery 1.8.1 and already tried by upgrading jQuery

Thanks

Comment: The plugin was written for jQuery 1.2.6 and lower, go through the plugin and replace `[@attributename...` with `[attributename...` or find a more up to date plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed jQuery Version to 1.2.6 and it's working cool

Thanks Kevin B for comment :

The plugin was written for jQuery 1.2.6 and lower, go through the plugin and replace [@attributename... with [attributename... or find a more up to date plugin. – Kevin B 14 mins ago